# Resume ubuntu configuration

Tags: shell, ubuntu, backup, reboot, timeshift

I had to reboot my ubuntu 22.04 lts laptop. Before to do it, I made a full copy of my system on an external harddisk with timeshift so that I could get it back on my computer as before. When I came back to ubuntu and wanted to reload my backups, I install timeshift, but my snapshot was not detected.

I tried to restore with timeshift but it, don't, I changed the various parameters, but it didn't change anything, I tried timeshift on a flash usb but it don't work. I tried to do it using "sudo cp" but it is not possible. So i searched on internet, i found the command "rsync -rl", it broke my ubuntu. i tried "rsync -rl" only for my user file, when i restarted the computer, each time i entered my password, i came back to the login page.